# Как отслеживать transform позицию курсора мыши в Unity2d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform

Я делаю игру песочницу, в ней объекты создаются нажатием мыши. Но я не нашёл кода который выдавал бы transform позицию, Input.MousePosition выдаёт позицию в пикселях а использовать это в transform position слишком крупно для игры с размером камеры 0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

```
ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3 position);
```

где `position` x,y - экранная точка, а z - глубина на которой нужно разместить обьект на сцене.